# JWT identify type of the token(refresh or access)

Tags: java, spring, jwt

I'm using the following library for parsing jwt tokens: **io.jsonwebtoken**. Is it possible to identify the type of the token?(whether it's refresh or access token)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we use OAuth2 with jwt there is additional field in claims - "**ati**" so we can use to identify whether it's access token or refresh token.